Help merging accounts
I am an infrequent user with two login, one tied to my private email address the other tied to my Google/gmail account. From my profile I see I have 6 or 7 accounts as shown in first attachment.
I would like to dissassociate from the Google/gmail account and have all my "accounts" associated with my private email address.
I perticularly value my accounts on Signal Processing and Space Exploration where I have earnt some decent reputation. The others are less important.
I found the "merge accounts" option but I was not sure I would get right result if I triggered that option. (I'm still working out the whole Meta/StackExchange/etc eco-system)
What is the best way for me to resolve this? thanks


You can follow the advice in this help article. Be sure to indicate in the Contact explanation which account you want to keep and which should be merged into it.
